# Hadoop Services not Running

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Recently installed the VM at the below link and was attempting to run the command `sudo hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/vagrant` as the HDFS user. However, Hadoop is throwing the below error message at me.

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/boxes/centos-6.6-64-nocm

```
-bash-4.1$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/vagrant
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 15:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 16:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 21:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 26:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 29:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 32:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 35:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 38:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 46:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 49:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 52:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 55:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 58:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 61:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 66:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 69:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 72:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 75:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 77:
: command not founddoop-env.sh: line 78:
mkdir: Call From bigtop1.vagrant/127.0.0.1 to bigtop1.vagrant:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I believe this means that none of the Hadoop services are running (even running hadoop -fs returns the command not found errors), but am unsure of how to resolve this issue. As well, I am not even seeing a /hadoop folder under /usr or /usr/local.

I was hoping to resolve this issue by using vagrant destroy -> vagrant up, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed line endings were windows format. Destroyed VM, correctly configured git for unix line endings `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, and remade. Works perfectly.